# Polymorphic base class with non-polymorphic child classes and abstraction

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Consider I have a TemplateEngine with the three classes:

- `TemplateEngine`
- `TemplateBase<T> where T : TemplateDataBase`
- `TemplateDataBase`

and the sample implementation:

- `SampleTemplate : TemplateBase<SampleTemplateData>`
- `SampleTemplateData : TemplateDataBase`

and now, in the engine, a getter function:

```
public T GetTemplate<T, U>() where T: TemplateBase<U>, new() where U : TemplateDataBase
{
    var template = new T();
    ...
    return template;
}
```

Since all implementations of `TemplateBase` will have exactly one valid value for `U`, like the sample, the type of `U` can be infered through the choice of `T`, and I shouldn't have to provide it to the `GetTemplate` method.

Other `TemplateData` classes contain completely different data and one shouldn't be able to use the wrong `TemplateData` class for a certain template.

If I now remove the `U` type parameter from the function call, I get "Incorrect number of type parameters", or, if I remove it from the function definition, the getter is no longer valid because "Cannot resolve U".

If I keep the parameter, I still am not allowed to do so because "There is no implicit reference conversion from `SampleTemplate` to `TemplateBase<TemplateDataBase>`".

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to use a type parameter that is a child of the type parameter defined in the `GetTemplate` method, you'll need to use a covariant type parameter. Which by definition

> Enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified

And since variance modifies can only be applied to interfaces or delegates, you'll need to create one of the two. Here's an example of using a [generic interface with a covariant type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance#generic-interfaces-with-covariant-type-parameters) that allows you the type parameter to be implied:

```
interface ITemplate<out T> where T : TemplateDataBase
{
    Type DataType { get; }
}

class TemplateBase<T> : ITemplate<T> where T : TemplateDataBase
{
    public Type DataType => typeof(T);
}

class TemplateDataBase { }

class TemplateEngine
{
    public T GetTemplate<T>() where T : ITemplate<TemplateDataBase>, new()
    {
        var template = new T();
        return template;
    }
}

class SampleTemplate : TemplateBase<SampleTemplateData> { }

class SampleTemplateData : TemplateDataBase { }
```

Note the `ITemplate<out T>`. This is what actually says that the type parameter is covariant.

And here's an example of the use site where the type is being inferred:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var engine = new TemplateEngine();
    var sampleTemplate = engine.GetTemplate<SampleTemplate>();

    Console.WriteLine($"{sampleTemplate.DataType.Name}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image]